# Get the object id when the object is created (Parse.com)

Tags: object, swift, parse-platform

I would like to set the string value to the object id when I create the object below. At the moment it prints "nil". Any ideas? Thanks

```
    var date:NSDate = currentDatePicker.date
    var DOB:NSDate = DOBPicker.date

    var user = PFUser.currentUser()

    var report = PFObject(className:"reports")
    report["name"] = nameTextField.text
    report["DOB"] = DOB
    report["date"] = date
    report["user"] = user
    report.saveInBackground()

    var ojId = report.objectId
    println(ojId)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`saveInBackground` is an asynchronous method, so it doesn't wait. The reason why the id is not set is because the entity has not been saved yet.

I think you should use `saveInBackgroundWithBlock:` and retrieve the object id form within the block (which is executed after the entity has been saved):

```
var report = PFObject(className:"reports")
report["name"] = nameTextField.text
report["DOB"] = DOB
report["date"] = date
report["user"] = user
report.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in
    if success {
        var ojId = report.objectId
        println(ojId)
    }
}
```

or maybe also `save`, which is performed synchronously - but **do not** use that from the main thread:

```
report.save()
var ojId = report.objectId
println(ojId)
```

Comment: I am slightly confused. Should I `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` as well as the code I am currently using?